# Scala Template Restrictions

Tags: scala, templates

In Scala, is it possible to provide arbitrary restrictions on templatisation types? In the particular case I'm working on, I have a class with two template parameters as follows:

```
class TwoWayMap[S,T]( )
{
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to work towards a thin wrapper around a pair of maps, allowing a user to look up keys in both directions. Restricting the two types to not being the same would allow looking up of values based on type, allowing me to write both of the following:

```
def apply( t : T )
def apply( s : S )
```

but obviously this doesn't work if the types are the same, so I'd like to restrict S != T

Comment: I think it would be better if you could provide the motivation for this instead. I don't think you can do this (not sure at all). Mostly we talk about only lower and upper bounds on generic types.

Seems to me like what you want is probably something obtainable by a better program design.

Comment: I've improved my example to show motivation!

Comment: You can of course do this at runtime using reflection, but it seems you want a compiletime fix, right? I would of course say that if people use the same type, they don't have a clue what they are doing anyway and you could suffice with a runtime exception.

Comment: The word *template* has a very specific meaning in Scala, and it doesn't seem that you are talking about anything even remotely related to it. It looks to me like you are talking about parametric polymorphism aka generics and not templates.

Comment: Are you sure you want to deal with situations where you don't distinguish `S` and `T` on the use side?

Comment: Scala's generic types / type constructors are most certainly _not_ templates in the C++ sense! The closest Scala comes to this is being able to _specialize_ generic classes (specific type parameters, to be precise) for particular primitive types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Joa Ebert wrote: One possible way to tackle this is to use the `Either` type:

```
class TwoWayMap[S,T] {
    def apply(k:Either[S,T]):Either[S,T] = k match {
        case Left(s) => Right(tForS(s))
        case Right(t) => Left(sForT(t))
    }
    // ...
}
```

Maybe it's too much boilerplate for you though.

Comment: No, absolutely not, that's really great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Due to Java type erasure both `def apply(t: T)` and `def apply(s: S)` will result in `def apply(...: Object)` which would be ambiguous.

So even if you would find a restriction for `S != T` this is not possible.